# How to create additional directories along with Azure AD using powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I was going through the Powershell support to the Azure, and while looking into the cmdlets provided by Azure PowerShell i did not found any reference for the command by which i can create new directory under my subscription.
May be I am missing something.

Can anyone tell me the exact way to achieve this programmatically (using pwoershell)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not expose the ability to create new directories via our REST APIs or PowerShell Module.

I believe this ability is only available through our Portals, in a non-automated fashion.

Can you go into more details about your scenario, where you would need to create multiple directories in an automated fashion?

Comment: Yes, agree with you Shawn. After investigation I could find that, such thing can be done only through the portal.

Comment: For one example, lets say we offer a service where a subscription for Azure is added to our site. Our site might need to automate a set of tasks for the user. We would have a subscription input, and a resulting output of a configuration of resources and automation.

Comment: Lets say we have a button that configures a subscription setup specifically for our service is brought in. They add the subscription Id and some basic information. They select a button to auto configure the subscription setup, and then they are all done!

This provides the ability for other companies to offer an option to bring our own subscription to a service provider. The API covers this in almost all cases, except for AD.

Comment: Alternatively, we must ask the customer to setup their own subscription, which in some cases, they may opt to use our hosting instead if they are not great with Azure management. We would prefer to host their services in Azure, as would the Azure team (more $$$ for them).

Basically, if 90% of Azure has API endpoints, it makes sense to have the last 10% as well, since it creates gaps in the system which need to be bridged with manual operations. This makes Azure look a bit clunky. We can have the manual process documented, but it still adds resistance to the use of Azure in these cases.

Comment: I would like to see a resolution for this limitation. Create an AD, Assign to a subscription, and continue in a fully automated fashion.